# Saving ruby's benchmark output to a file

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I wrote a short ruby script to time the run of a command line utility I have. I'm using the ruby's `Benchmark`module as so:

```
Benchmark.bm(" "*7 + CAPTION, 7, FMTSTR, ">avg:") do |bench|
  #this loops over a  couple of runs
  bench.report("Run #{run}: ") do
    begin
    Timeout::timeout(time) {
      res = `#{command}`
    }
    rescue Timeout::Error
    end
  end
end
```

The timeout use is probably a bit crude but should be ok for my needs. The problem is `Benchmark.bm` just prints the benchmark results. I'd like to be able to save them to a file for further processing (it's run a couple of times in a single script so I don't want to just consume the terminal output - seems way too much effort for something this simple)

Comment: It looks like the easiest way would be check the source code of the library and do something myself. :(  They use STDOUT in several places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is easier than you might think, just add the following lines to the beginning of your script.

```
$stdout = File.new('benchmark.log', 'w')
$stdout.sync = true
```

And everything is redirected to the file, off course if you need some output to the console you will have to stop the redirection like this.

```
$stdout = STDOUT
```

EDIT: here the scipt i used to test this

```
require 'benchmark' 

$stdout = File.new('console.out', 'w')
$stdout.sync = true

array = (1..100000).to_a 
hash = Hash[*array]

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x| 
  x.report("Array.include?") { 1000.times { array.include?(50000) } } 
  x.report("Hash.include?")  { 1000.times { hash.include?(50000) } } 
end
```

Comment: I tried this a couple of minutes ago and unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the following error: `benchmark.rb:207:in '*': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)`. I think this is related to reto's comment under my question.

Comment: I tried it on my pc and it worked, i'll publish the testscript i used, i use windows 7 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.7. I'll try to upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Matz just announced wat he lounch of 2.0 that 1.8 will die soon, so you 'd better do, success !

Comment: So yeah, this is correct. Thank you so much for your help. I changed the call I was making to run the benchmark when changing `$stdout` and that broke things. I didn't realise I did that. Thanks again!